# Inconsistent local storage values across views angularjs

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, angular-ui-router

I'm building an app in angularjs. My backend uses tokens to manage sessions. The token is sent on every request in the headers, and the response contains a header with a new token value that I should update.

I'm using *localStorage* to store the token value. The problem I'm encountering is the following:

When I enter the route */users* for example, I request the users, receive a token in the header and update it locally on *localStorage*. Then I go to */products* for example, I request the products, receive another token and update it locally on *localStorage*. When I go back to */users*, the browser, or *angularjs*, or *ui-router*, I don't really know who is doing it, is getting the view from cache, and the problem is that *localStorage* also has cached values, which has an old token value, which is invalid, and any request from there to the backend will fail to authenticate.

Any one has any clues on getting over this?. I want my *localStorage* to be consistent across views, even if they're cached, I don't want my *localStorage* to be cached.

I'd appreciate the help!.

**UPDATE**

This is how I manage *localStorage* from an *auth* service.

```
auth.saveToken = function(token) {
    $window.localStorage['my-token'] = token;
};

auth.getToken = function() {
    return $window.localStorage['my-token'];
};

auth.removeToken = function() {
    $window.localStorage.removeItem('my-token');
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not messing up the keys/domain/prefix you use for your localStorage? I can't believe that localStorage.get('sameKey') returns a 'cached stale value' - your issue must be somewhere else. Maybe post some code... are you using angular-local-storage (https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)?

Comment: Just updated the question with code from my *auth* service.

Comment: I just tried with angular-local-storage instead of $window. I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: are you somehow using multiple domains/subdomains?  the other thing that comes to mind is that you are writing more often/less than you think: add a console.log into all your service calls and check what you write and what you read.

Comment: Nope everything is in the same domain. Thanks for your help bro. Let me log on every auth service call and check if something is being done wrong!.

Comment: I found out that the problem is not because of localStorage caching. When I go back to */users*, the request somehow was cached and the response headers are the old ones and then it replaces the localStorage token with the old token.

Comment: Any clue how to overcome that?. I'm using restangular by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out what the problem was. In my *users* service I was setting an attribute named 'all' like this:

```
users.all = Restangular.all('users').getList();
```

Since it is not a function, when using *users.all* I was accessing the promise returned the first time from *Restangular.all('users').getList();*.

That's why the response seemed to be "cached". It was totally my fault.

The solution was to make *users.all* a function, like this:

```
users.all = function() {
    return Restangular.all('users').getList();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

to turn off http level caching you can either

- adjust the caching header configuration that the server sends out so that it does not allow the browser to cache the response - something like `response.header('Expires', '-1'`);
- add a query param that always changes to the request you send to the server (e.g. `domain.com/api/something?timestamp=12341234`)

Comment: I have no control over the backend at the moment, I'll give it a try with sending a timestamp in the query string, I'll let you know if that fixes it. Thanks